# Can creating more than 500 hiddenBoxFor make the loading horribly long?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a simple question for you.

I have a view where, in a for loop, I create this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].OtherObj.m_ObjName)@Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].m_Card.m_CardName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].m_NbInStock)@Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].m_NbInStock)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].m_QtyAllowed)@Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].m_QtyAllowed)</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].m_IsForSelling)</td>

                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].m_ObjID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].m_OtherObj)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].m_OtherObjID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].m_IsAllocated)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].m_IsReallyThere)
                </tr>
            }
```

You get the idea. I figured that I had to create hiddenboxes for every properties of the object, and the list can be populated with MANY items. 500 right now is an approximative, it could grow much more.

My point is that the process "seems" to roll normally until the debug hits the very last line of code in the view which is:

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "SearchIndex")
</div>
```

And, at that point, it takes about a few minutes or four before the page finally display. I'm afraid it will go skyrocket once I have all my data available.

Is it because of all the hiddenfields needed? Maybe it may take a while to generate the HTML page?

Thank you for your wisdom.

EDIT **

I think I have the culprit:

```
section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I used to put this line of code at the end of my view, can this be the cause?

Comment: 4.0.
Also, I will add another piece of code which, I think, may be the origin of all this waiting.

Comment: It's not just the Razor process to generate the view, it's also the download time to the browser and the browser rendering time. You should paginate on the server, for many reasons.

Comment: It's going to be render time in the browser or Javascript processing time. In the Chrome developer tools, you can use the Timeline feature to see exactly where the time is being spent.

Comment: As Andre Calil says: 'Paging'. Why would you need so much data all at once? It could save a lot of speed just getting the data again when you really need it. Since they are all hidden, It looks like you don't really need it. Html is mostly just representation of the data a user needs to see, not all of your actual data.

Answer (score 2):

> 500 right now is an approximative, it could grow much more.

I suggest that you back up a step. This is probably a bad idea for a variety of reasons:

- Massive request size whenever the page is POSTed
- Many fields that can be potentially tampered and thus all need to be validated
- Large DOM
- Load on the rendering engine (this shouldn't take *minutes*, but parsing all those expressions isn't free).

### Alternatives

- Break content into smaller pages; and/or use data paging and/or lazy loading.
- Use session state for user-specific data that you are consistently round-tripping with the page.
- If the data is not user-specific (e.g. a list of products), `Cache` is a better alternative than `Session`.
- Make more trips to the database. Modern databases are extremely "smart" about caching queries and data; pulling this data up when needed may not even hit the disk subsystem (and thus will be both fast and efficient).
- Local storage (probably not applicable based on your sample data, but worth mentioning)